# Only one file `.js` per page is recommended?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

I read several articles saying it is not recommended to put javascript code within the page.

I would like to hear from you. 
How do you do with that code that is specific to that page?

### Sample

In my **Project.cshtml** I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.project-status').parent('a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            DoSomething();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Have in my **myfunctions.js** file:

```
function DoSomething() {
    alert('test')
}
```

On every page of my project, this situation repeats itself.

### Question

You make a single file `.js` and put there all the javascript for all pages?

Or make one file per page, and make reference that file on the page?

Or put the js code that is specific to the page in the page itself?

### The problem we want to solve

I had this question for I am with the following problem:

In my application I have:

**Project.cshtml**

When you click a link, load the page **ProjectPhotos.cshtml** via ajax into a `div#photos`

The problem is that on my page **ProjectPhotos.cshtml** have the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.project-status').parent('a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            DoSomething();
        });
    });
</script>
```

As this page is loaded via ajax, this script will not in the HTML markup.

If this script was in a separate JS file, click on the link, I could load the file dynamically.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If the scripts are fairly small, concatenating the files into one is better because you reduce the number of connections (the browser will usually use just a few simultaneous connections).

But if the scripts are big, and the scripts are not needed on all pages, it's probably better to split it up. But still preferably only one file per page.

Try both options and disable/empty cache in your browser and test...

Comment: A recommended way to get both benefits is to keep different code in different files until it's time to put it into production, and then combine as much of the code into a single file as is practical.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is to put everything in one file for two reasons.  One maintenance is easier there is only one script to deal with instead of searching through seven.  Second once the script is loaded it is cached.  Meaning it is ready for all your other pages as well.  Assuming you don't have scripts that are huge for each individual page the overhead is not really that much.

Comment: I don't see one file as being easier to maintain. I prefer 7 files with 1000 lines of code than 1 with 7000 lines. That just depends on how big your application is.

For the user, the best is to keep as minimum files as possible, but for the developer the best is to separate them into several files as modules.

As it been said, develop in separate files to combine them into one file in production. That way, you can have even modules for every page in your application, being easier to maintain.

Comment: Maintenance is not easier with one ginormous file... I'll take a dozen logically separated JS files over a single 4k LOC JS file for development any day.  But what's good for development is not always good for production.

Comment: @pedrochaves true, but in this case I'm seeing 1 or 2 functions that are specific to each page not 1000 lines.  However, I think 1000 LoC for a script would qualify as rather large and then I would split it up per the second part of my post.

Comment: @qw3n agreed. In an application with little JS there is actually no need for several files, and it would really make maintnence harder then it's supposed to be.